# I'll replace the datasource username in application.properties and work with it after completing spring boot authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, entitymanager, application.properties

I have username aba and password aba123 in the application properties,
Before authentication, I get the user trigramme and set it in the application properties:

```
            spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sybase:Tds:${HOSTNAME}:2500/Manager
            spring.datasource.username=aba 
            spring.datasource.password=aba123   
      
    
      @PersistenceContext
                 private EntityManager em;
                 System.setProperty("spring.datasource.username", "vca" );
                 System.setProperty("spring.datasource.username", "vcavca" );
                 
                 Query query = em.createNativeQuery("{call S0_DISCObureaucz_java()}");
                 List<Object[]> storedProcedureResults = query.getResultList();
```

> However, it does not function. Could you kindly assist me?

Comment: You may need to re-phrase your question little bit as it is unclear to me at least.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.